# Testing w/ older versions of .Net

Tags: .net, configuration

I have .Net 3.5 on my dev machine but am forced to deploy to a .Net 2.0 machine.  Without wiping my current install is there a way to "dumb down" my version of .Net so it behaves like .Net 2.0?  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the properties for your solution in Visual Studio, you can change the Target Framework to ".NET Framework 2.0". Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just testing, my solution would be to create a [virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en), with just .NET 2.0.

Then deploy it to the testbox and verify everything works.